# T-SQL to select every nth date from column of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column of dates.  They are all workdays.  I would like to generate a list of dates that are 'n' days apart.  For example, starting with the most recent date, I want to find the date n days before it, 2n days before it, 3n days before it, etc.  I could use a while loop but I wanted to know if I could use SQL set operations instead.  Can it be done?

Comment: How do you want to use it? It's not clear at all what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  If your dates are all workdays and n=5, then you will quickly not have a date that is in your table.

Answer (score 2):

Find the difference between the most_recent_date and dates in your table, then use the modulo function, where n is the interval.

```
SELECT date
FROM my_table
WHERE mod(most_recent_date - date, n) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect case for a CTE:

```
DECLARE @LastDate datetime;
DECLARE @N int;    
DECLARE @NCoefficientMax;

SELECT @N = 1, @NCoefficientMax = 10;

SELECT @LastDate = MyDate
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MyDate DESC

WITH mycte
AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(dd, @N, @LastDate) AS NextDate, @N AS NCoefficient
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, @N, NextDate), @N + NCoefficient AS NCoefficient
FROM mycte WHERE NCoefficient < @NCoefficientMax 
)

SELECT NextDate FROM mycte
```

Where **@NCoefficientMax** is the max coefficient for N.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dateadd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) funcion
and make select with join to self table.

What that you need to do it - 
Insert the result to temporary table,
with additional column then contain the [row_number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) then order like the result

simple example:

```
declare @t1 table (d datetime, row int)

insert @t1
select d, row_number()over(order by d)
from T1 
order by d

select T1A.*, datediff(day,T1A.d,T1B.d) as dif
from @t1 as T1A
left join @t1 as T1B on T1A.row = T1B.row-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mostRecent datetime2

SELECT @mostRecent = MAX(dateColumn)
FROM table

SELECT columns
FROM table
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, dateColumn, @mostRecent) % n) = 0
```